# Give a variable varying value for each item in a string?

Tags: python

So I'm making a simplified Enigma-style code where each character is changed into another, but the encoding changes after each character. What I have so far is:

```
message = input("Message?")
message = message.lower()
state1 = int(input("State 1?"))
code1 = []
code2 = []
for character in message:
    number = ord(character) + state1
    if number >= 123:
        number = number -26
    code1.append(number)

print (code1)

for character in code1:
    word = chr(character)
    code2.append(word)

print (code2)
```

So if state1 = 1, "abc" will become "bcd", however I want state1 to increase by one for each character so that "abc" would become "bdf" (a+1=b, b+2=d, c+3=f). I'm aware that there are other (perhaps better) ways of achieving what I have so far, but this is what I best understand. Is there a way to achieve my goal this way, or do I need a different approach?

Comment: Just increment the `state1` in your first `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is increment the counter you are using to encode the message. In your case that counter is `state1`, so something like this should work.

```
for character in message:
    number = ord(character) + state1
    if number >= 123:
        number = number -26
    code1.append(number)
    state1 += 1
```

Comment: Oh, that was far simpler than I thought. So the "for character in" acts as a loop, I guess? As in, it runs through the block of code for the first letter, then repeats for the next? Thank you, this has been very helpful. @Haris

Comment: @Imbalance, Yes, thats exactly how that loop runs.